# Debug a server for android on nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, server

I'm trying to create a `node js` server for android phones. How can I create it at home in a local network without outer internet connections? I have wifi at home so my phone can connect to local network. I use official `socket.io` tutorial and I don't know what to write here (instead of `http://chat.socket.io`):

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://chat.socket.io");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}
```

Comment: can u give link for tutorial?

Comment: usually u should give ur system ip and port number

Comment: @rakeshkashyap http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: @rakeshkashyap can I use `socket = IO.socket("http://localhost");`

Comment: ur ip address and port where the app is running... in the format http://ip:port/

Comment: no you cannot use localhost... as localhost refers to android's localhost... not ur system where node server is running

Comment: @rakeshkashyap Ok, I suppose it's answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open command prompt on your PC and hit `ipconfig`. note down your wireless IP address. Let's assume it to be `192.168.1.10`. you can also set a static IP for your PC on your router. Next from your socket io code check what port number you are using. for example

```
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
```

says that you are using port 3000.

Hence in your Android code you need to use http://192.168.1.10:3000/